# .bat file not executed after conda activate py36

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd.exe, uac, anaconda

I got a .bat file containing:

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
conda activate py36
python C:\Users\User\button5.py
conda deactivate
```

If I run it directly from command line it works, but wenn I execute the .bat file it stops after conda activate py36 with no error message.

Edit: I see now the problem, when the script is executed in normal prompt it dosen't work, it works only in admin command prompt. But when I run the .bat as admin the normal prompt starts. How can I force it to open with admin cmd?

Comment: When you run it from the command line, do you use the Anaconda Prompt, or just the regular command or powershell window? Also, when I do a websearch for `run conda activate in bat file` I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24678144/1256347), does that help?

Comment: It works in anaconda and  admin cmd, in standart cmd I get an error from the .py script because of a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can make the batch file auto-elevate:

```
goto="Batch" /*
:Admin
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
conda activate py36
python C:\Users\User\button5.py
conda deactivate
exit /b 0
:RunAsAdmin
color 4f & echo Running Admin Shell, Please wait.... & call cscript //nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" RunAsAdmin "%1" & exit /b
:"Batch"
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls
openfiles >nul 2>&1 || goto :RunAsAdmin
goto :Admin
:"JScript" */
function RunAsAdmin(self, arguments) { WSH.CreateObject('Shell.Application').ShellExecute(self, arguments, '', 'runas', 1) }
if (WSH.Arguments.length>=1 && WSH.Arguments(0)=='RunAsAdmin') RunAsAdmin(WSH.ScriptFullName,WSH.Arguments(1));
//
```

It will check for elevated priviliges, and if not present an UAC dialog for prompting for administrative priviliges. Another way:

```
@echo off & powershell.exe -command "& {Start-Process cmd.exe -ArguemntList 'conda activate py36 & python C:\Users\User\button5.py & conda deactivate' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Comment: Ok I am including another way

Comment: Okay there was also a minor spelling error in the code. It works now properly in the command prompt. Thank you, thats amazing!

Comment: Welcome a lot :-)!